# How can we determine the group with the presentation $G:=\left\langle g,h\mid g^4=h^4=1,hg=g^{-1}h \right\rangle?$

Tags: finite-groups, group-presentation

Please how can we determine the finite group whose presentation is given as:
$$G:=\left\langle g,h\mid g^4=h^4=1,hg=g^{-1}h \right\rangle?$$

*See [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1171802/how-can-we-determine-the-group-with-the-presentation-g-left-langle-g-h-mid-g?r=SearchResults#comment2388062_1171802) for some context from the person asking this question.*

Comment: As a first step you could try to prove that all elements of $G$ can be written as $g^ih^j$ with $0\le i\le 3$ and $0\le j\le 3$.

Comment: Thanks J.P. Your hint implies that $|G|\leq 16$. But I am pretty sure that $|G|\geq 16$ (as no group of order less than 16 has this nature). So, going by your suggestion, $|G|$ must be 16. However, I am still unable to identify the exact nonabelian group of order 16 that satisfies this.

Comment: Next try to show that both $g^2$ and $h^2$ are in the center of $G$. (I'm not sure yet which group we will get, I just work comment to comment, I hope you don't mind. It might be that the given relations imply additional relations, but our group has at least $8$ elements.)

Comment: Forget my last comment. Just try to find a semi-direct product of two cyclic groups of order $4$ that is the image of your group $G$. This shows $|G|\ge 16$, and $|G|\le 16$ you know by my first comment. Hence $G$ is isomorphic to that semi-direct product.

Comment: Using GAP, try `F:=FreeGroup(2); rels:=[ (F.1)^4, (F.2)^4, (F.1)*(F.2)*(F.1)*(F.2)^(-1) ]; G:=F/rels; StructureDescription(G);`.

Comment: [This comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2660734/finding-m-n-k-for-which-g-mn-and-g-is-nonabelian-where-g-is-given-by#comment5497252_2660734) might help :)

Comment: [This is what I meant by GAP](https://www.gap-system.org).

Comment: So $\langle g\rangle$ is normal. It follows that $G$ is a semidirect product of $\mathbb{Z}_4$ by $\mathbb{Z}_4$.